# Spring cloud Eureka client not registering

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-netflix

I have recently updated my micro-services project from Spring boot 2.0.5 to 2.7.4.

Also, updated Spring cloud dependencies to 2021.0.4.
Miragrate from Netflix Zuul to Spring cloud Gateway.

My Eureka Server is running on PORT 8000, which I can access on browser and see the Eureka Dashboard.

Gateway is running on port 8001, which registers successfully with Eureka, and I can see it's status "UP" in the Dashboard.

But no other service are registered on Eureka. The application.yml file of all other services are almost similar to the gateway-service. Below are some code snippets of one of the services :

**Problem 1 - Application name UNKNOWN**

```
DiscoveryClient_UNKNOWN/192.168.1.3: registering service...
```

**Problem 2**

```
Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}, exception=java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) stacktrace=com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

**Eureka-server config**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-service

cloud:
  config:
    uri: ${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}
server:
  port: 8000

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka
  server:
    enableSelfPreservation: false

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework: ERROR
    com.debugfactory.trypz: ERROR
  file:
    name: logs/eureka-service.log
```

**Gateway-service Application.yml - This registers with proper name with Eureka**

```
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: reactive
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  application:
    name: zuul-service
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 10MB
      max-request-size: 10MB
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
      routes:
      - id: sms-service
        uri: http://sms-service/
        predicates:
        - Path=/sms/**

server:
  port: 8001
  max-thread: 100

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8000/eureka/}
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true

logging:
  file:
    name: logs/zuul-service.log
  pattern:
    file: "%d %-5level [%thread] %logger{0} : %msg%n"
  level:
    org.springframework: INFO
    com.bayview: DEBUG
    org.netflix: INFO
```

**SMS-Service <- This tries to look for Eureka port on 8761 with name UNKNOWN**
**Application.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: sms-service
  data:
    mongodb:
      authentication-database: admin
      database: sms
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: local

server:
  port: 8022
  servlet:
    context-path: /sms
  tomcat:
    max-threads: 10

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.web: ERROR
    org.hibernate: ERROR
    com.cryptified.exchange: DEBUG
    org.springframework.data: ERROR
    org.springframework.security: ERROR
    org.springframework.web.client: DEBUG
  file:
    name: logs/sms-service.log

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8000/eureka/}
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
```

Comment: Did you try starting the apps with —debug and turned up logging to see more output from the Eureka client? Of course, you can also use a debugger at startup.

Comment: Yes, tried that. edited my question with the error I get on the client. All clients except cloud-gateway (Zuul) tries to register on Default Eureka port 8761

Comment: Wild guess, but Spring may have changed the port (unlikely) or the context path (more likely) for Eureka registration. Check the release notes leading up to the version you upgraded to. If that’s the case, you’ll have to tell the clients about the change.

Comment: I did that too, my confusion is that, the gateway-client has the same properties as other clients. The gateway does register with correct name, but no other service. I also checked the dependencies in POM.XML of gateway-client and other services, they do share the same Eureka Client dependency <spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client>

Comment: I have the same problem and only the Api Gateway registers

Comment: https://dimitr.im/fix-eureka-localhost

Comment: @skyho in my case, I had to set spring.profiles.active=local in every micro-service yml file to actually pickup the YML properties. I realized that missing this, Spring was not picking up entire application.yml file and using the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

- gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.4")
    set('testcontainersVersion', "1.17.4")
    mapStructVersion = '1.5.3.Final'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'

    implementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:${mapStructVersion}"
    annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapStructVersion}"

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter'
   
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

.....
```

- application.yml in your project

```yaml
URI_TO_SERVER_CONFIG: http://localhost:8888

spring:
  application:
    name: name_project_your
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: ${URI_TO_SERVER_CONFIG}
  config:
    import: configserver:${URI_TO_SERVER_CONFIG}

  profiles:
    active: microservice, discoveries, name_project_your
```

**Application configs on git-repository**

- application-discoveries.yml

```yaml
SERVER_PORT_SERVICE_DISCOVERY: 8761
IP_ADDRESS_SERVICE_DISCOVERY: http://localhost

eureka:
  instance:
    instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${random.uuid}
  # https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/docs/current/reference/html/#changing-the-eureka-instance-id
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: ${IP_ADDRESS_SERVICE_DISCOVERY}:${SERVER_PORT_SERVICE_DISCOVERY}/eureka
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 5
```

- name-project-your.yml

```yaml
DB_IP: 127.0.0.1
DB_PORT: 5432
DB_DATABASE_NAME: name_db
DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://${DB_IP}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_DATABASE_NAME}
DB_USERNAME: postgres
DB_PASSWORD: postgres
DB_SCHEMA: your_schema

spring:
  application:
    name: name-project-your

  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
    discovery:
      enabled: true


  datasource:
    url: ${DB_URL}
    username: ${DB_USERNAME}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD}

  flyway:
    baseline-on-migrate: true
    locations: classpath:db/migration
    create-schemas: true
    default-schema: ${DB_SCHEMA}
```

- application-microservice.yml

```yaml
eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true

logging:
  level:
    com:
      netflix:
        eureka: debug
        discovery: debug

server:
  port: 0
```